# Object calling an object

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Can someone explain to me the `(*this)` pointer and demonstrate how it would be used as far as an object calling another object of the same class. What I don't understand is how you would refer to two numbers in a member function of different 2 different objects of the same variable name. For example, multiplying two numbers.

```
a.Multiply(b);
//....
Numbers::Numbers Multiply(Numbers auggend)
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this pointer:
```

The member functions of every object have access to a pointer named `this`,which points to the object itself.When we call a member function,it comes into existence with the value of `this` set to the address of the object for which it was called.Using a `this` pointer any member function can find out the address of the object of which it is a member.It can also be used to access the data in the object it points to. Example:

```
void setdata(int ii)
{
   i=ii;         // one way to set data
   this->i=ii;   // another way to set data
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this pointer` stores the address of the class instance and can be used to initialise values

Answer (score 0):

(*this) is a pointer to your instatniation of a class.  In your example if Numbers class had a data value "value":

```
a.Multiply(b);
....
Numbers::Numbers Multiply(Numbers auggend)
{
  return (this->value) * (auggend.value);
}
```

Comment: so (this->value), is pointing to the "value" variable in object "a"and "(auggend.value);" is refering to the "value" variable in the multiply paramater?

Comment: Indeed they are.  The reason for (this*->*value) vs (auggend*.*value) is left as an exercise for the reader ;-).

Answer (score 0):

First off, your example doesn't look quite correct. I believe that should be:

```
Numbers Numbers::Multiply(Numbers auggend)
{
}
```

Anyway, with that said, `this` is simply a variable of type `Numbers * const` that points to your member variable. So from your example `a.Multiply(b)`, `this` will hold the value of `&a`.

Let's say you had some other function that took a `Numbers *`:

```
void DoSomething(Numbers *num);
```

You can then call that function with `this`:

```
Numbers Numbers::Multiple(Numbers auggend)
{
    DoSomething(this); 
    DoSomething(&auggend);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
   int num;
   void foo(int num)
   {
      num = 10; //local variable num is set to 10
      this->num = 10 ; //class member num is set to 10
   }
};
```